# Do pin lock static relief valves need to be replaced after activation?

Tags: corny-keg

If the static relief valve on a pin lock keg has vented pressure (i.e at 130 psi) does the valve cease to work? Does it need to be replaced with a new static relief valve?

Background:

I was watching a video on youtube regarding corny kegs the other day. In the video a statement was made regarding the static relief valves on pin lock corny kegs. Specifically, the statement made was that once a static relief valve has been activated (i.e at 130 psi) it must be replaced. The video did not state what happens if you do not replace it. Perhaps the keg simply does not hold pressure, or worse it no longer automatically vents pressure. Unfortunately I do not remember the link.

Edit: Found the link. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeHF87wr4hE

Answer (score 3):

I contacted CornyKeg.com, the people who created the video. They said that the video they created was erroneous and that static relief valves do not need to be replaced if they have been used.

Here's a quote:

> I am not sure why that video is even on the internet anymore. Those static relief valves will reset and usable again. As long as they do not leak there is no need to replace them. Sometimes the get loose and you will need to tighten them with a wide blade flat screw driver in the square recess on the back. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I've manually popped relief valves countless times with no trouble. As for running the pressure up to the 130 psi range, I don't know why anyone would. I'm not even sure how you would, unless the beer is still fermenting vigorously. My CO2 regulator is only good for 100 psi, and some I've seen only go up to 50. I doubt if I've ever gone beyond 40, even when I was in a hurry to carbonate.

In fact, I had one old Firestone keg with a stemmed, cone-shaped (i.e. irreplaceable) relief valve seal. When that developed a nick, I didn't hesitate to put in a dab of silicone or epoxy--I forget which, it was a long time ago--and continue using it.

Comment: Yep I'm talking about that irreplaceable relief valve which is present on pin lock kegs. What was the significance of the epoxy? Just to fill a gash?

Comment: To seal the relief valve entirely, since I keep the pressure well below the danger zone. Of the six Firestone kegs I bought at the same time, four didn't even have pressure reliefs, so I figured one less wouldn't matter as long as I was careful.

Comment: Interesting. Yeah I'm looking to use a corny as a primary fermenter. I'd like to know I have a backup co2 escape plan other than the blow off tubing attached to the gas post. I can't seem to find any information on how to determine if a static relief valve is in working order or not though.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to use a keg as a primary, but if I were forced to do so and the relief valve didn't have a manual trigger (which I assume is the case), I'd simply drop the end of the blow off tube into a jug of e.g. sulphite solution, turning it into a high-capacity airlock. I doubt like heck you'd have to worry about that clogging up, though you might have froth bubbling into the jug along with the CO2.

Comment: I am trying to ferment under pressure and in a closed environment. I will transfer the beer from the primary keg to the secondary keg and then attach a spunding valve so the beer naturally carbonates, essentially creating "real ale" aka cask ale. In order to have a completely closed system the gas post needs to be kept on. The inconvenient fact is that there is very little space for blow off to travel through in the gas post, hence why I would like a back up pressure release method. Hopefully I won't have to worry about blowoff at all by filling the primary only roughly 1/2 to 2/3s full.

Comment: See: http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f13/closed-system-pressurized-fermentation-technique-44344/

Comment: Sure, now you tell us ( kidding ;-). Since that's your ambition, I wonder if something like this: http://www.williamsbrewing.com/PIN-LOCK-RELIEF-VALVE-P121.aspx might provide the insurance you'll want.

Comment: Ah, that is the static relief valve that sits in the keg lid. The pin lock equivalent of http://www.williamsbrewing.com/KEG-LID-VALVE-P92.aspx. What you are thinking of is the spunding valve -> http://www.williamsbrewing.com/0-60-ADJUSTABLE-PRESSURE-RELIEF-VALVE-P3453.aspx

Comment: Hmm. Should be an easy plumbing/adapting job to clip a short chunk of e.g. braided hose from a pinlock CO2 fitting to that adjustable spunding valve. Seems to me that, by using the CO2 supply side as your pressure relief, you could pretty much forget about the one built into the lid, or seal it off entirely. Heck, you get a pressure gauge as a bonus. Only a suggestion, since this kind of thing is beyond my present ambitions and likely to remain so. Best of luck!

Comment: Yep. You get the idea. That's more or less how people are doing it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey, @fthinker, have you done this plan? It went ok with this setup? Thinking about try the same with old pin-lock kegs, please share if you had problems with your relief valve or something. Thanks

Comment: @jards I don't primary ferment in kegs. I had an unfortunate accident where a thermos holding active yeast blew up in my fridge destroying one of the tempered glass shelves. The yeast had been in there for only 4 hours as well. I was cleaning up little glass shards for hours. Instead now I ferment in a plastic bucket and transfer to a keg for extended aging. I slap the spunding valve on and regulate the build up of co2 over time. I do have a friend at work that does primary in his keg using the valve and he has had good success. I just don't like the fact that there is one point of failure.