# How to remove/service static relief valve on a pin lock keg?

Tags: equipment, corny-keg, pressure

i have a pin lock keg with a leaking static relief valve. The lid looks like this: [image]

[image]

I can't figure out how to remove the innards of the relief valve to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Just put a tool that fits this square hole and unscrew it counter clockwise (normal thread). A large enough flat screwdriver can be used between 2 corners, to. Inadequate tools could damage the plastic and make things more difficult. Find a good tool before you try.

A socket wrench with the "smaller" adapter fits almost perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Is this pressure release valve missing a pull ring?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/13186/is-this-pressure-release-valve-missing-a-pull-ring) it looks like you might unscrew it from the bottom. Not enough reputation to post comments.

Comment: The OP's picture shows a PRV on a pin-lock corney keg, which has no pull ring, but you are talking about the PRV on a ball-lock corney keg, which *does* have a pull-ring.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just get a new lid.  Several kegging supply sites sell new lids at reasonable prices and you could cut the pressure relief off that one, insert a grommet and now you have a fermentor.